# Chosen Jquery Plugin on asp:ListBox - Multiple controls generated

Tags: entity-framework, jquery-chosen

I have a User Control which is customized using Chosen Jquery Plugin as follows

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" CodeBehind="ManyToMany_Edit.ascx.cs" Inherits="Blah.ManyToMany_EditField" %>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="lbltest"  />


<%--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/style.css">--%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/prism.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/chosen.css">
<%--<style type="text/css" media="all">
/* fix rtl for demo */
.chosen-rtl .chosen-drop {
left: -9000px;
}
</style>--%>
<script src="../../Content/chosen.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Content/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Content/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<%--<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMultiSelect" data-placeholder="Choose a Team Member…" class="chosen-select" multiple Style="width: 350px;" runat="server">--%>
<div >
<asp:ListBox  ID="ddlMultiSelect" SelectionMode="Multiple" data-placeholder="Choose …" multiple class="chosen-select"   runat="server" >

</asp:ListBox>
</div>

<form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var config = {
'.chosen-select': {},
'.chosen-select-deselect': { allow_single_deselect: true },
'.chosen-select-no-single': { disable_search_threshold: 10 },
'.chosen-select-no-results': { no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!' },
'.chosen-select-width': { width: "95%" }
}
for (var selector in config) {
    $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
}
</script>
</form>

<header>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=ddlMultiSelect.ClientID %>").change(function () {
            var arr = $(this).val();
            if (typeof arr === 'object' && arr instanceof Array) {
                document.getElementById('<%=lbltest.ClientID%>').value = arr.toString();
            }
            else { document.getElementById('<%=lbltest.ClientID%>').value = ""; }
            console.log(arr);

        }
    )
});
</script>
</header>
```

I then use it in entity framework to show my Many 2 Many edit view. It works fine for one of the fields but for the other one it generates 2 Input boxes. 
If I turn off Chosen and use a normal Listbox it works as expected by generation one control for each field. So I think it is something to do with Chosen.

Screenshot below
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved this bit

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
             var config = {
                 '.chosen-select': {},
                 '.chosen-select-deselect': { allow_single_deselect: true },
                 '.chosen-select-no-single': { disable_search_threshold: 10 },
                 '.chosen-select-no-results': { no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!' },
                 '.chosen-select-width': { width: "95%" }
             }
             for (var selector in config) {
                 $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
             }
</script>
```

from the user control (Feild Template ) to the Insert and Edit pages . The config needs to be assigned only once in a page load. It works now. I think now I have a very good Many2Many field template which I will post on the nuget sometimes later.